# Prolog enumerate and test, will recursion work?

Tags: prolog

I have to make a predicate which will take 2 numbers `N`,`M` and will output `"yes"` when `N`,`M` are positive numbers and there are two numbers `A`,`B` such that `A+B = M` and `A*B = N`.

*EDITED CODE:*

For example `M = 18`, `N = 45`:

`A = 0`, `B = 18`, `M = 0+18` (true), `N = 0*18` (false) so it has to go next with `A = 1` & `B = 17` and check again...

```
numbers(M,N) :-
  M>0 ,
  N>0 ,
  A is 0,
  B is M,
  numbers(N,M,A,B).
numbers(M,N,A,B) :-
  M =:= A+B,
  N =:= A*B.
numbers(M,N,A,B) :-
  M =:= A+B,
  not( N =:= A*B),
  A is A+1,
  B is B-1,
  numbers(M,N,A,B).
```

I don't know how to enumerate `A` and `B` variables. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are they restricted to integers, I assume? And what prolog interpreter are you using? You might want to look at the CLPFD library.

Comment: @mbratch Yes only Integers. For example M=18 and N=45 will return yes. While M=12 and N=25 no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add and multiply and check... see [is](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28is%29/2)/2 for arithmetic

*edit* my advice was a bit simplistic, I totally forgot a hint to easily generate integers ranges in Prolog, using nondeterminism:

```
numbers(M,N) :-
   between(1,M,A),between(1,N,B), M =:= A+B, N =:= A*B, writeln((A,B)).

?- numbers(18,45).
3,15
true ;
15,3
true ;
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

I look at it as a factoring problem:

```
%
% are M and N magic?
% 
magic(M,N) :-
  M > 0 ,
  N > 0 ,
  factor(N,A,B),
  M is A+B
  .

%
% factor/3: compute the factors of a positive integer
%
factor(N,F1,F2) :-
  N > 0 ,
  Limit is floor(sqrt(N)) ,
  factor(1,Limit,N,F1,F2)
  .

factor(F1,Limit,N,F1,F2) :-
  F1 =< Limit ,
  F2 is N div F1 ,
  0  is N mod F1
  .
factor(X,Limit,N,F1,F2) :-
  X < Limit ,
  X1 is X+1 ,
  factor(X1,Limit,N,F1,F2)
  .
```